# Links to download and print a PDF doc (w/o PHP)

Tags: javascript, pdf, hyperlink, download

Could you please help me make two different links: one to launch the open/save as pdf, another the print dialog boxes (e.g. in Adobe Reader application)

```
<a href="http://gasparean.com/resume.pdf">My Résumé</a>
```

I mean, maybe I need to put the file on server in another way (without an extension, for instance; please, check how's that done here: http://gasparean.academia.edu/gasparean/CurriculumVitae

Please note, that the hosting I use, does not support PHP, so I need a solution without that scripts.

Thank you!

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking or what you're tried and how that attempt isn't working.  If you're just looking to link to a PDF file, you've done that in the question.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, PHP is the best option. If you can use .htaccess files on your server, or you can access your Apache config files, you could add this line in there:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Note: If you add this in .htaccess, it will make any PDF in that directory download -- and if you set this line in your Apache config files, it will force any PDF to download.

You could use the HTML5 download attribute, but that only really works in Chrome at the minute anyway...

```
<a href="http://gasparean.com/resume.pdf" download="resume">My Résumé</a>
```